# React - How can i add Geolocation (getCurrentPosition) in my react-redux code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, geolocation, google-geolocation

#### I would to add geolocation.getCurrentPosition in my code below using **react** and **redux** and then send the **coordinates** (Lat and Long) to the Local Storage but i don't have any idea !

> I deleted the HTML parts of the form (city, postalCode .. to avoid repetition

Anyone can help me with please

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import FormContainer from '../components/FormContainer';
import CheckoutSteps from '../components/CheckoutSteps';
import { saveShippingAddress } from '../actions/cartActions';

  const ShippingScreen = ({ history }) => {
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const { shippingAddress } = cart;

  const [address, setAddress] = useState(shippingAddress.address);
  const [city, setCity] = useState(shippingAddress.city);
  const [postalCode, setPostalCode] = useState(shippingAddress.postalCode);
  const [country, setCountry] = useState(shippingAddress.country);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(
      saveShippingAddress({ address, city, postalCode, country })
    );
    history.push('/payment');
  };

  return (
    <FormContainer>
      <CheckoutSteps step1 step2 />
      <h1>Shipping</h1>
      <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Form.Group controlId="address">
          <Form.Label>Address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter address"
            value={address}
            required
            onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>
        <Button type="submit" variant="primary">
          Continue
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </FormContainer>
  );
};
export default ShippingScreen;
```

Comment: There are custom hooks like [useGeolocation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hook-geolocation) that package this functionality.

Comment: Thnx i solved it !